# How to check revision history of java source code

Tags: java, version-control, java-7

I want to check the revision history of JAVA's

> java.util.logging.LogManager

for this method

> demandLogger

I can see [here](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/logging/LogManager.java/?v=diff&id2=7-b147) the difference between java 7 versions but in which exact version this method changed, I can not figure out.

Answer (score 2):

There is no complete publicly browsable source-code repo for Java.  However if you are prepared to install Mercurial, you can then "clone" the repos to get your own copy and analyse the history locally.

Reference:

- [OpenJDK Repositories](http://openjdk.java.net/guide/repositories.html) explains how to do it.
- The [OpenJDK Mercurial Repositories](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/) catalog shows what is available.

---

I found [mirrors](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror) of *some* OpenJDK Java7 source repos on GitHub ... but they don't cover the entire history.  (They seem to stop at around 7_u6.)